# how do I find my AIR Application publisherID?

Tags: air

I need to find the publisherID of my native AIR application so I can use the browser invocation feature.

I have a working AIR Native Application Installer project (.exe) built with FlashBuilder 4.5 as a "signed native installer" using a self-signed certificate.

But I look in the install folder and cannot find the file 'META-INF/AIR/publisherid'. Also, I tried logging 'NativeApplication.nativeApplication.publisherID', but it shows as an empty string.

How do I get a publisherID?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke an AIR application using the described API even if the publisherID is missing. Just leave it blank, like that:

airSWF.launchApplication(appID, "", arguments);

Comment: Forgot about this for awhile, but I finally got it to work. The above is true. However, I needed this example to get it right: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dg_part_8_1.html

Answer (score 1):

`publisherID` is legacy.  it's no longer used but continues to be supported for AIR applications compiled with AIR 1.5.2 and earlier.

[AIR application descriptor elements:  publisherID](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-8000.html#WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d12939cc14ab-8000)

you should refer to values in your descriptor file instead.  for example, this is how you can obtain the version of your application based on that tag's value in the XML descriptor file:

```
var descriptor:XML = NativeApplication.nativeApplication.applicationDescriptor;
var ns:Namespace = descriptorFile.namespace();

trace("Version " + descriptor.ns::versionNumber);
```

Comment: my ultimate goal is to do a browser invocation of the native app.

    var appID:String = "com.example.air.myTestApplication";
    var pubID:String = "02D88EEED35F84C264A183921344EEA353A629FD.1";
    var arguments:Array = ["launchFromBrowser"]; // Optional
    airSWF.launchApplication(appID, pubID, arguments);

do I substitution the Version for pubId?